# Resolution of multi-sampled frame-buffer with multiple color attachments

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, multisampling, deferred-rendering, deferred-shading

Trying to implement Anti-aliasing on top of deferred shading, I'm attempting to use multi-sampled render buffers and then resolve the samples with a buffer-blit pass.

1. As is traditional in deferred shading, I am rendering the scene with a dedicated shader issuing 3 color outputs:

   - Positions
   - Normals
   - Diffuse & specular
2. Those are then used in a lighting-computation pass resulting in the final scene texture
3. The scene texture is rendered to the screen on a full-screen quad using a simplistic shader

As you probably guessed, the on-screen MSAA is not applied to the content of scene texture when being rendered to the screen:
to achieve anti-aliasing I thus chose to use multi-sampled render buffers in step 1) and introduced an extra step 1.1) for resolution. Of course the multi-sampling is only necessary/useful for the color map, not the other 2 maps.

My problem & question is that apparently, a frame buffer with multiple render-buffers/color attachments can only be defined for the same types of attachments ; meaning that if one attachment is multi-sampled then all others must be.

This becomes a problem for Positions and Normals buffers during resolution, because the geometry and lighting is affected as a result of anti-aliasing.

- Is my understanding valid regarding frame buffer attachments?
- Is there a way around it, in order to still have multi-sampling on the Diffuse&Specular map, but not affect the other maps?

```
    // Create the frame buffer for deferred shading: 3 color attachments and a depth buffer
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &gBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    {
        // - Position color buffer
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &gPosition);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, gPosition);
        glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 8, GL_RGBA16F, w, h);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, gPosition);

        // - Normal color buffer
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &gNormal);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, gNormal);
        glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 8, GL_RGBA16F, w, h);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_RENDERBUFFER, gNormal);

        // - Color + specular color buffer
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &gColorSpec);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, gColorSpec);
        glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 8, GL_RGBA, w, h);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_RENDERBUFFER, gColorSpec);

        unsigned int attachments[3] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2 };
        glDrawBuffers(3, attachments);

        // - Generate the depth buffer for rendering
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &sceneDepth);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, sceneDepth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h);
        glRenderbufferStorageMultisample(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 8, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, sceneDepth);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // Create a frame buffer with 3 attachments for sample resolution
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &gFrameRes);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gFrameRes);
    {
        glGenTextures(1, &gPositionRes);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPositionRes);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB16F, w, h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gPositionRes, 0);

        glGenTextures(1, &gNormalRes);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormalRes);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gNormalRes, 0);

        glGenTextures(1, &gColorSpecRes);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gColorSpecRes);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gColorSpecRes, 0);
    }
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);


    // ...
    //
    // Once the scene is rendered, resolve:
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, gBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, gFrameRes);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2);
    glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, sw, sh, 0, 0, sw, sh, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_LINEAR);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

The result of the code sample above is that lit object's edges are showing artifacts of inappropriately dark/black or bright/white pixels, presumably because their position and/or normal have been altered in the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This becomes a problem for Positions and Normals buffers during resolution, because the geometry and lighting is affected as a result of anti-aliasing.

It's supposed to be.

It is logically incoherent to have positions and normals not use multisampling, while the diffuse/specular colors acquired are. Remember what multisampling is: each pixel has multiple samples, and different data from overlapping triangles may write to different samples in the same pixel. So you can have diffuse/specular colors from two or more triangles all in the same pixel. But that also means you should have positions and normals associated with each of those sub-pixel colors too. Your lighting pass won't make sense otherwise; you'd be using position&normal values for colors that didn't generate them.

Proper multisampling with deferred rendering is *expensive*. The only way to make it work is to multisample everything, and then perform your lighting pass computations on a *per-sample* level. Since most of the performance gain of multisampling compared to super-sampling is not doing computations per-sample, you're only getting the benefits of multisampling (rather than supersampling) in your geometry pass, not your lighting pass.

This is why people try to avoid multisampling when using deferred rendering. This is why pseudo-antialiasing techniques like FXAA and whatever exist.

Comment: "The only way to make it work is to multisample everything, and then perform your lighting pass computations on a per-sample level". Well, that is technically not the _only_ way. One can actually store the information if all samples in this particular gbuffer pixel come from the same primitive in the gbuffer itself, and use that in the lighting pass to only do it per sample for pixels where this is not the case, like this [nvidia example](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/graphicssamples/d3d_samples/antialiaseddeferredrendering.htm)  demonstrates.

Comment: Marking as answered, because I understand your point @NicolBolas, BUT, I would still make the following remark: to me, anti-aliasing is not a technically/physically realistic principle (referring to your comment that I should be using multi-sampled geometry just like colors are), instead it is just meant to fool the eye by simulating smoothness - with that in mind, it could still make sense, to have discreet/accurate (not multi-sampled) geometry applied to a slightly incoherent/wrong colouring on edges (multi-sampled). Especially because those pixel are mostly fading in their surrounding.

Comment: On your last point, I agree that NSAA, FSAA seem to be the next thing to try, which I have started to actually - just didn't have much success so far. @derhass I feel that you are making an interesting suggestion, but I'm not a 100% sure I get it. I will try to think about it a little harder :)

Comment: @Smoove: I meant FXAA. But you shouldn't think of anti-aliasing as something made up. It is a real thing, defined mathematically by analog-to-digital signal processing. It's not something to "fool the eye" or "simulate smoothness"; it's a real concept.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes FXAA thank you - I actually knew what you meant, but still reproduced the mistake myself :D